# If doing "math foo bar", how to get foo and bar inside Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I run Mathematica as "math foo bar", what variable(s) hold foo and 
bar? I'm guessing it's $Something, but haven't found it.

Googling told me Mathematica accepts command-line options like -pwpath, 
-pwfile, but I couldn't find the right search phrase for actual 
command line arguments (not options).

Comment: If you can access the documentation, searching for "command line" returns `$CommandLine` as the first hit...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$CommandLine` variable holds the command line arguments.

```
$ math foo bar
In[1]:= $CommandLine
Out[1]= {math, foo, bar}
```