# How do you access ARGV in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, command-line-arguments, argv

I'd like to write command line scripts in Mathematica, but I can't seem to find an `Argv[i_Integer]` like function. (The docs are FANTASTIC otherwise.)

Comment: similar question: [If doing “math foo bar”, how to get foo and bar inside Mathematica?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7149252/211232)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$CommandLine` works for Mathematica, MathematicaScript, MathKernel, and math.

args.ma:

```
#!/usr/bin/env MathKernel -script

Print[$CommandLine]
```

Example:

```
$ ./args.ma a b c
{"MathKernel", "-script", "./args.ma", "a", "b", "c"}
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems that [$ScriptCommandLine](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$ScriptCommandLine.html) is the variable you would need for this, **assuming you're using [MathematicaScript](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/MathematicaScript.html) for scripting**. If you use `math` or `MathKernel -script` it would be [$CommandLine](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$CommandLine.html).

Other relevant discussions: a [rather old one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148057/615464) and one in the MMA [toolbag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148057/615464).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, `MathKernel` reports `$ScriptCommandLine` as empty `{}`, no matter the actual arguments supplied. And `MathematicaScript` reports `Could not find Mathematica installation directory.`

Comment: @mcandre Are the executables on your path?

Comment: @mcandre .... and did you see this line in the docs: "The first line of the script must contain the -script option, which must be the **last** option on the line."

Comment: @mcandre "If no -script option was provided, $ScriptCommandLine gives an empty list."

Comment: @mcandre This all still assuming you're using MathematicaScript.

Comment: @mcandre What's the value of $InstallationDirectory when you run Mathematica from the frontend?

Comment: `$InstallationDirectory` = `"/Applications/Mathematica.app"`, from both `MathKernel -script` and from the Mathematica GUI.

Comment: @mcandre MathematicaScript is new in v8.  What version do you have?

Comment: @mcandre It seems my assumption you were using MathematicaScript was wrong. In that case you should try `$CommandLine`.

Comment: Congrats on 10k, Sjoerd! Welcome to the club of deleted crap viewers :)

Comment: @yoda Thanks, and now the Mathematica gold badge, that'll impress my kids ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm fond of passing things in using environment variables:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Environment.html

Comment: Helpful, but it's a bit more manual than specifying command line flags.